# Is there any benefit to using wsHttpBinding SSL Transport Security in conjunction with Message Security?

Tags: .net, wcf, ssl, wcf-security

In WCF when using `wshttpbinding` with Message Security (which encrypts the serialized XML sent over the wire), why do we need SSL Transport Security, which also encrypts with an SSL certificate?

Comment: Note this is actually a good question and not obvious to most people, so i've taken the liberty of reformatting the question in the spirit of the original post

Answer (score 0):

To address this question it's probably best to start with some basics of the [**Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

By understanding some of these key points, the answer to your question should become clear

**WCF Key Security Features**

Any Service-Oriented Architecture (SOA) needs to support security features that provide auditing, authentication, authorization, confidentiality, and integrity for the messages exchanged between the client and the service.

- **Auditing**. Effective auditing and logging (i.e. non-repudiation). Non-repudiation guarantees that a user cannot deny performing an operation or initiating a transaction.
- **Authentication**. Confidently identify the clients of your service. These might be end users, other services, processes, or computers.
- **Authorization**. Determine what system resources and operations can be accessed by the authenticated user.
- **Confidentiality**. The process of making sure that data remains private and confidential, and that it cannot be viewed by unauthorized users. Encryption is frequently used to enforce confidentiality.
- **Integrity**. Guarantee that data is protected from accidental or deliberate modification. Integrity for data in transit is typically provided by using hashing techniques and message authentication codes.

More information on the above can be found here : [**WCF Security Fundamentals**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650862.aspx)

---

**WCF security model**

In WCF, you have several choices for providing transfer security, which primarily breaks down into (but not limited to) the following Transfer Security modes

- **Transport**. Mutual authentication and message protection are provided at the transport level
- **Message**. Mutual authentication and message protection are provided at the message level
- **Both**. Mutual authentication and message protection are provided at both the transport and message

There are other hybrid variations to this regime, more information on this topic can be found here : [**Message and Transport Security**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648863.aspx)

---

**Transport security**

Transport security in regards to WSHttpBinding uses the HTTP transport and the primary mechanism for securing the transport is [Secure Sockets Layer (SSL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) over HTTP, commonly called [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure).

Transport security provides only a point-to-point secure channel between a client and a server, if that server is a load-balancer or a proxy server, the resulting server has direct access to the content of the message if not secured

[image]

More information on Transport security can be found here : [**Transport Security Overview**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729700%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

---

**Message security**

Message security in regards to WSHttpBinding uses the WS-Security specification to secure messages. The WS-Securityspecification describes enhancements to SOAP messaging to ensure confidentiality, integrity, and authentication at the SOAP message level (instead of the transport level).

Message security differs from transport security by encapsulating the security credentials and claims with every message along with any message protection (signing or encryption). Applying the security directly to the message by modifying its content allows the secured message to be self-containing with respect to the security aspects. This enables some scenarios that are not possible when transport security is used.

[image]

More information can be found here [**Message Security in WCF**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733137%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

---

**Transport and message security**

Now to answer you question, in certain advanced situations transport and message security can be combined. An example would be transport security to your load balancer or some sort of proxy, and message security to its final destination to assure that the message hasn’t changed and or the content has remained private respectively.

Another example using a hyprib approach might be the scenario in a user-centric web application, where the web application runs on its own server and talks to a business service on a separate server. The web application server talks on behalf of the user with the business server

In most cases combined transport and message security is not needed, and since transport security uses hardware acceleration and message security does not, there maybe extra performance overhead that is not required or suitable

More information about transport and message security can be found here [**Message and Transport Security**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648863.aspx)